# change color of svg images with css

Tags: css, html, vector, svg

I have an svg image on my page which I am including like this:

```
<img src="image.svg" class="arrow"/>
```

- I want to change its color with css. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you need to edit the image with a text editor and copy that in the html to do that. otherwise you can also use the very none-supported css property `-webkit-filter`

Comment: I figured out a nice way to do this, I think it's by far the best way out there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement/11978996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`hue-rotate`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/#toc-what), but it's [not really supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Comment: thanks - this was really useful actually. Found a nice jsfiddle with a few properties that might work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/w3cplus/wThjx/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you're trying to make it a rollover image, create a new SVG image with the changed colour, then [look at this code](http://joemaller.com/js-singleroll.shtml) to use JavaScript to make it a rollover image.

If you're not using it as a rollover, then I can't do any more.