# SVG wont change colour with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

So I have the following SVG image:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<title>ic_toggle_on_1</title>
<style>
    .circle {
        fill:#3165bd;
    }
</style>
<path class="circle" d="M8,0a8,8,0,1,0,8,8A8,8,0,0,0,8,0ZM6.78,11.73,3.17,8.12,4.58,6.7l2.2,2.2,4.64-4.63,1.41,1.41Z"/>
</svg>
```

Which I am trying to change the colour on hover with the following CSS:

```
.toggleCircle[data-state="open"]:hover img {
    /*fill:#047ad4;*/
    fill:red!important;
}
```

Which works fine if I use say `border` but for some reason the fill attribute cannot amend the SVG. I've read that as long as the fill isn't inline this should be overwritable by CSS and although there is [change color of svg images with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696191) this is 6 years old and I believe quite out of date.

Am I missing anything obvious as to why this SVG won't change colour?

Comment: you are change the color of an img not an svg

Comment: oh, you are including the svg as an image ??

Comment: Yes - sorry for any confusion. The image is in HTML and I want to change the colour with css. Having real difficulties!

Comment: so you cannot :) you need to consider some workarounds like two svg or applying filter

Comment: It can definitely be done ... https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/

Comment: yes if you are using SVG inside the HTML and not within an IMG

Comment: It works just fine with <style>
    .circle {
        fill:#3165bd;
  transition:.5s;
    }
    .circle:hover {
        fill:red !important;
    }
</style>

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to work when the data-state tag is open within the CSS.

Comment: .circle { fill:#3165bd; transition:.5s; } .circle[data-state="open"]:hover { fill:red !important; } and you set the data attribute with JS or jQuery or you can manually add it as a test.

Comment: But the circle tag doesn't have the data-state hence why its done in the CSS file.

Comment: Than try placing the CSS outside the SVG. LIke <style>.toggleCircle[data-state="open"]:hover .circle</style><svg>....</svg>

Answer (score -1):

You might need a more specific selector. More specific selectors overwrite less specific ones. Maybe try something like

```
.circle.my-circle:hover { fill: red }
```

and

```
<path class="circle my-circle" ...>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I require my css selector as it is due to a data-tag change